# What is the undocumented -Y option to wget?

Tags: wget

I noticed a script using `wget -Y off ...(bunch of stuff)...` which I hadn't encountered before.

Looked it up in the man page and in `wget --help` and found nothing.

But it definitely exists as an option; contrast it with the non-existent option `-Z`:

```
# wget -Y
wget: option requires an argument -- 'Y'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
# wget -Z
wget: invalid option -- 'Z'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
# wget --help | grep -- -Y
#
```

What is this undocumented option?

Comment: It is likewise not documented in the info page at https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: UTSL -- Use the Source, Luke!

Comment: FWIW, busybox's wget implementation (used, for example, in alpine) still has the option: `-Y on/off Use proxy` (and it's missing `--no-proxy`)

Comment: @Geier that's quite relevant as the script I saw using this is a debian installer script (in a foreman provisioning template) that actually runs on busybox.  It uses `wget -Y off ...` to fetch the "finish" script from foreman, that is then run "in-target" (with access to normal non-busybox utilities).

Answer (score 34):

A bit of digging turned up the relevant commits:

- [Remove -Y from --help, and example in manual.](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/commit/?id=0734d8dd3744825c4db56ef0f50bcff111efa18e) (2007)
- [Restore old behavior of -Y.](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/commit/?id=e3acbd2aaf2c1a6556b20243781f4e4b83dbd2a2) (2005)

Apparently -Y is an ancient switch preserved only for backward compatibility, that allows turning the use of a proxy off (or on??).

The modern replacement for `-Y off` appears to be `--no-proxy` which is documented in the current manual as:

```
       --no-proxy
           Don't use proxies, even if the appropriate *_proxy environment variable is defined.
```